# How to persist a salt with specified lenght in the database

Tags: java, symfony, hash, salt, sha512

I already have a database which contains a table named User, this table contains a table salt, password etc...

1. salt column has data with length 43
2. password column has data with 88 length

my database was created by `symfony(ORM+FOSUserBundle)` he use sha512.

I am trying to get a salt and a password , and store them into the database from desktop java application, so I tried this Class:

```
import com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class SHA512 {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SHA512.class);
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "SHA-512";
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 5000;
    private static final int SALT_SIZE = 43;


    /**
     * Private constructor.
     */
    private SHA512() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "0000";

        try {

            byte[] salt = generateSalt();
            log.info("Password {}. hash algorithm {}, iterations {}, salt {}", password, ALGORITHM, ITERATIONS,
                    BaseEncoding.base64().encode(salt));
            byte[] hash = calculateHash(password, salt);
            boolean correct = verifyPassword(hash, password, salt);

            log.info("Entered password is correct: {}", correct);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }


    private static byte[] generateSalt() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_SIZE];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        return salt;
    }

    private static byte[] calculateHash(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        md.reset();
        md.update(Bytes.concat(password.getBytes("UTF-8"), salt));
        byte[] hash = md.digest();

        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
            md.reset();
            hash = md.digest(hash);
        }
        return hash;
    }

    private static boolean verifyPassword(byte[] originalHash, String password, byte[] salt) throws
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] comparisonHash = calculateHash(password, salt);

        log.info("hash 1: {}", BaseEncoding.base64().encode(originalHash));
        log.info("hash 2: {}", BaseEncoding.base64().encode(comparisonHash));

        return comparePasswords(originalHash, comparisonHash);
    }

    /**
     * Compares the two byte arrays in length-constant time using XOR.
     *
     * @param originalHash   The original password hash
     * @param comparisonHash The comparison password hash
     * @return True if both match, false otherwise
     */
    private static boolean comparePasswords(byte[] originalHash, byte[] comparisonHash) {
        int diff = originalHash.length ^ comparisonHash.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < originalHash.length && i < comparisonHash.length; i++) {
            diff |= originalHash[i] ^ comparisonHash[i];
        }

        return diff == 0;
    }
}
```

I need a salt with lenght 43, But `BaseEncoding.base64().encode(salt)` output salt with lenght equal 60.
I modified the SALT_SIZE to 30 and `BaseEncoding.base64().encode(salt)` output a salt with length equal to 40 but, when I add a user with that salt and with the hash generated, I can't Login with this user from my web application(already said that FOSUserBundle controls authentication and encode/decode algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this right, you have an error in your digest encoder implementation.

Reference points:

**[MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php)**

**[BasePasswordEncoder.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/BasePasswordEncoder.php)**

When you request to manually generate digest, there are basically two steps:

1. Hash the concat: `password` + `{` + `salt` + `}`
2. For each additional iteration: hash the concat of `previous digest` +  `salt` (note that this step does not add `{` or `}` chars)

So, I see two issues in you implementation:

1. It looks to me that you have not included those `{` and `}` in iteration #0
2. You have not included the salt in any of later iteration

Hope this helps a bit...